# Extract inner text from anchor tag string using a regular expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am new to angular js . I have `regex` which gets all the `anchor tags`. My reg ex is

```
/<a[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>/g
```

And I am using the `match` function here like ,

```
var str =  '<a href="mailto:abc.jagadale@gmail.com" style="color:inherit;text-decoration:inherit">abc.jagadale@gmail.com</a>'
```

So Now I am using the code like

```
var value = str.match(/<a[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>/g);
```

So, Here I am expecting the output to be `abc.jagadale@gmail.com` , But I am getting the exact same string as a `input  string` . can any one please help me with this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use `$("a")` selector and loop through the result list to get it's `href` attrib?

Comment: Smells of [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Do me a favour and add `content:">"` inside your `a` tag's `style` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?**

You are trying to parse the HTML string with a regex it will be a very complicated task, just use  DOM or jQuery to get the links contents, they are made for this.

- Put the HTML string as the HTML of a jQuery/DOM element.
- Then fetch this created DOM element to get all the `a` elements
  inside it and return their contents in an array.

This is how should be your code:

```
var str = '<a href="mailto:abc.jagadale@gmail.com" style="color:inherit;text-decoration:inherit">abc.jagadale@gmail.com</a>';

var results = [];
$("<div></div>").html(str).find("a").each(function(l) {
  results.push($(this).text());
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var str = '<a href="mailto:abc.jagadale@gmail.com" style="color:inherit;text-decoration:inherit">abc.jagadale@gmail.com</a>';

var results = [];
$("<div></div>").html(str).find("a").each(function(l) {
  results.push($(this).text());
});
console.log(results);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, Awsome solution. just one thing here, I am getting all the URL's But there are some values which are " "  . Can you tell me what exactly is this ?

Comment: @ganeshkaspate Maybe these are empty `a` elements, check your HTML string or please post it here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the group inside the anchor tags. The regular expression already matches the inner group `([^<]+)` But, when matching there are different ways to extract that inner text.

When using the Match function it will return an array of matched elements, the first one, will match the whole regular expression and the following elements will match the included groups in the regular expression.

Try this:

```
var reg = /<a[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>/g

reg.exec(str)[1]
```

Also the match function will return an array only if the g flag is not present.

Check https://javascript.info/regexp-groups for further documentation.

Comment: Still getting the same output

Comment: Hey , I am using a for loop here. So, Can you please take a look at my code .      var reg = /<a[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>/g;
          var isOrphanPresentInUrl;
          var variable = responseData.match(/<a[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>/g);
          console.log(variable.length);
          for(var i=0; i <= variable.length; i++) {
              var urlText = reg.exec(variable[i])[1];
              isOrphanPresentInUrl =  urlText.includes(orphan);
          }
          if(isOrphanPresentInUrl) {
                return true;
              } else {
                return false;
              }}

Comment: @ganeshkaspate Hey, try taking a look at other answers here because many agree on not using regex for this, and also update the question with the code you attempted to past in here. Since it will be easier to the rest of the users to help you on your question.

Answer (score 0):

### Brief

Don't use regex for this. Regex is a great tool, don't get me wrong, but it's not what you're looking for. [Regex cannot properly parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) and should only be used to do so if it's a ***limited*, *known* set of HTML**.

Try, for example, adding `content:">"` to your `style` attribute. You'll see your pattern now fails or gives you an incorrect result. I don't like to use [this quote](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) all the time, but I think it's necessary to use it in this case:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Use builtin functions. jQuery makes this super easy to accomplish. See my **Code** section for a demonstration. It's way more legible than any regex variant.

---

### Code

#### DOM from page

The following snippet gets all anchors on the actual page.

```js
$("a").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="mailto:abc.jagadale@gmail.com">abc.jagadale@gmail.com</a>
<a href="mailto:abc2.jagadale@gmail.com">abc2.jagadale@gmail.com</a>
```

#### DOM in string

The following snippet gets all anchors in the string (converted to DOM element)

```js
var s = `<a href="mailto:email3@domain.com">email3@domain.com</a>
<a href="mailto:email4@domain.com">email4@domain.com</a>`

$("<div></div>").html(s).find("a").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="mailto:email1@domain.com">email1@domain.com</a>
<a href="mailto:email2@domain.com">email2@domain.com</a>
```

Comment: I have more than 1 links in the document.

Comment: @ganeshkaspate it'll work. I edited my answer to include two anchor examples.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for such a great answer. Here, tried this way just, but what is happening it is taking each and every anchor tag from the html document from the URL as well. So, I don't want that . I have a html file like a document and it has some URL's , I want to have that text. Now that document is html but I get it in a string format from server side. So, that whole document is html but getting as a string. So, I was using the regex for this.

Comment: @ganeshkaspate I added a new snippet showing how to use a normal string, convert it to DOM and then find anchors.

Answer (score 0):

Given the use case of parsing a string, instead of having an actual DOM to work with, it does seem like regex is the way to go, unless you want to load the HTML into a `document fragment` and parse that.

One way to get all of your matches is to make use of `split`:

```
var htmlstr = "<p><a href='url'>asdf@bsdf.com</a></p>"

var matches = htmlstr.split(/<a.+?>([A-Za-z.@]+)<\/a>/).filter((t, i) => i % 2)
```

Using a regex with split returns all of the matches along with the text around them, then filtering by index % 2 will pare it down to just the regex matches.