# need RegEx to match <a> tag and href

Tags: javascript, regex, nsregularexpression

my regex is 
`/<a[\s]+([^>]+)>((?:.(?!\<\/a\>))*.)<\/a>/g` to match all `<a>` tag in string.
but i need to match `<a>` with a special `href` link.
for example : Only `<a>` tags that have `href="https://example.com"` links

Comment: Is this answer your question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48063160/extract-inner-text-from-anchor-tag-string-using-a-regular-expression-in-javascri

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) or do it with a temporary DOM element. And then you can filter a tag using [attribute equals selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```js
let str = `sdsdsd 
<a href="https://sample.com" >abc</a>
<a href="https://example.com" >abc</a>`

const temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = str;

temp.querySelectorAll('a[href="https://example.com"]').forEach(ele => console.log(ele.outerHTML))
```

[Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)